# detect reload or refresh event on a page and what triggered it

Tags: events, refresh, reload, detection

If a page is being reloaded or refreshed intermittently without user intervention- is it possible to 1

1. detect the event
2. know what process is triggering it?
3. who is triggering it?

Comment: This wouldnt be possibly from the website point, considering it refreshes and restarts all the code immediately, however logging the IP in an API and then detecting they have refreshed would be alot easier. When the webapp loads send a call to the api and see if they were only just on, if so then they have just refreshed.

Comment: Thank you Isaac. The goal is to try determine why the page is being refreshed intermittently - what is causing that to happen.